# Can expressjs be used with nodejs net to listen for TCP protocol

Tags: node.js, express

i am creating a chat server using expressjs. Is it possible to use expressjs and nodejs net module for the application to listen to a tcp port 7677 for messages? Thanks!

Comment: Express is a HTTP library.  What would you expect it to do other than what net.CreateServer does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless they are http messages (unless you just mean your app running on `http://yourhost:7677`)

Comment: Nope it is telnet myhost 7677

Comment: Yeah express will not help, but writing this 'from scratch' is not too hard really:  https://gist.github.com/creationix/707146